# How can I use JMX to register my own mbean with a custom typed attribute?

Tags: jmx

I defined a mbean with a get method returning a self defined type,then implement it and register it.Then while running , It always says "has parameter or return type that cannot be translated into an open type".I believe I should use CompositeData to support this.But I don't know how to do it?Any advises?

Answer (score -2):

You can use MXBean. Check [this](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/mxbeans/).